# Synchronize access to JPA EntityManager

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring, Hibernate and JPA Entity Manager. When fetching different regions of the UI concurrently (via jquery/ajax) , I would like to synchronise access to JPA Entity Manager, as otherwise it results in shared references to collections exception. How do I achieve this ? I have a controller that calls service methods in the backend which are responsible for calling get/save etc on entitymanager.

Comment: A JPA entity manager is not thread safe, and should not be used by several threads. Each thread should have its own instance.

Comment: Thanks ! How do I inject a separate instance to each request (ui controller method probably) ? Currently I am injecting a Entity Manager (extended persistence mode) into service layer.

Comment: Locking object might help with appropriate mode

Comment: How ? Sorry, but I can not figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply lock on the object with specific mode.

- Entity Manager : `entityManager.lock(entity, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC);`
- Query : `query.setLockMode(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC);`
- NamedQuery : lockMode element

Lock mode `OPTIMISTIC` is synonymous to `READ` & `OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` to `WRITE`.

---

**Edit :** From Documentation

> If transaction T1 calls for a lock of type LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC on
>   a versioned object, the entity manager must ensure that neither of the
>   following phenomena can occur:
>
> - P1 (Dirty read): Transaction T1 modifies a row. Another transaction T2 then reads that row and obtains the modified value, before T1 has
>     committed or rolled back. Transaction T2 eventually commits
>     successfully; it does not matter whether T1 commits or rolls back and
>     whether it does so before or after T2 commits.
> - P2 (Non-repeatable read): Transaction T1 reads a row. Another transaction T2 then modifies or deletes that row, before T1 has
>     committed. Both transactions eventually commit successfully.
>
> Lock modes must always prevent the phenomena P1 and P2.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, what you are suggesting is that I introduce the entitymanager by means of injection into the spring controller (currently its in service), and then use the locking as described for operations that I think need it. I can not lock entitymanager always as not all operations need it to be locked.

Comment: @Sup You don't have to lock entityManager, but only the required objects on which operations are being carried out concurrently. Also, I think there is no need to change anything in controller/service. Here access or entityManager itself isn't synchronized, but the shared results, their access is synchronized.

Comment: Let me explain my situation again. I have a controller method a() which calls serviceA.loadAllEntityA() , and another one b() which also calls serviceA.loadAllEntityA() , and both a() and b() are called in parallel. Now from controller methods, I want a way to lock the access to EntityA from the methods a() and b().

Comment: @Sup So you have to integrate that in method loadAllEntityA(). In this method as mentioned in my post, you can lock entity whose state is being accessed/modified concurrently. If possible update your question with relevant code, it will help others too.

Comment: Great, thanks a ton. Will post some code as soon as I have something working. Meanwhile I am stuck somewhere else ...

Comment: I could not get it to work as there are several entities which are involved internally, and I dont want to lock each one of them. I tried locking one entity, and then it failed for another (shared access when trying to flush from one thread). Looks like I am doing something wrong. What are the best practices to handle such situations...

Comment: @Sup Entities whose state is changing, only those needs to be locked. But if numerous entities are involved, then you may try to synchronize the method.